# Issue with Serverless deploy of smart contract-Dependency mismatch -Package.json,Package-lock.json error

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, serverless, package-lock.json

I'm trying to deploy my smart contract serverless(AWS lambda) and I'm using Truffle framework.

The code is getting deployed in an earlier system(earlier it was deployed here). Now I have updated the smart contract version .When I am deploying it. I am not able to in my new system due to dependencies mismatch n version change.I tested my smart contract in local system using ganache. there uts working fine. When deploying serverless I am getting the issue.

Below is the error screenshot

enter image description here - Below are the dependencies in package.json.

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.256.1",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"openzeppelin-solidity": "^1.12.0",
"pug": "^2.0.3",
"solc": "^0.4.24",
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.50"
and all the above have been updated to newer versions..
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.3.6",
    "ethereumjs-abi": "^0.6.7",
    "ethereumjs-tx": "^2.1.0",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^2.3.0",
    "promise-mysql": "^4.0.4",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "scrypt": "^6.0.3",
    "serverless": "^1.46.1",
    "solc": "^0.5.10",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "websocket": "^1.0.29"
  }
}
```

i have updated package.json and package-lock.json to newer versions  but the project is not getting deployed serverless.

Comment: Asha, make sure all required node modules are also packaged with the deployment package.

Comment: yes they r packaged still the issue is coming..the dependencies r updatedin package.json but in package.json-lock it is in older version..let me explain my procedure--1.did git clone of project (older version)..2.made changes to package.json(updated dependencies) 3.redeployed using aws 4.getting errors